# iOS, Bluetooth connection dialog, customizing message

Tags: ios, bluetooth

```
dispatch_queue_t centralQueue = 
dispatch_queue_create("no.nordicsemi.ios.nrftoolbox", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
bluetoothManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc]initWithDelegate:self queue:centralQueue];
```

By calling above codes, following dialog is popped up.[image]

Is there a way to change the popup message? It is automatically popped, not defining any alert view. I've already described "Privacy - Bluetooth Peripheral Usage Description" in info.plist, but it is not related to the popup message.

Thanks,

Comment: The dialog is presented by iOS so you cannot customise it. You can prevent it from being displayed by setting https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanageroptionshowpoweralertkey to false

Comment: Thanks, then, is it possible to change language? not English, but other language?

Comment: The language will be set by the device language setting.